# Why does using .abs() and np.abs() return different values for a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math

i've got code that looks like this:

```
# Fourier Transfrom LETSGOOOOO whooooo
df_ = df['Open']
fft = tf.signal.fft(np.asarray(df_.tolist()))
fft_df = pd.DataFrame({'fft':fft})
fft_df['absolute'] = fft_df['fft'].apply(lambda x: np.abs(x))
fft_df['abs'] = fft_df['fft'].abs()

fft_df.head()
```

I found the code using the lambda function in a tutorial and wondered why the person chose to use that instead of simply using .abs() and so I added a column where I used .abs() to check if there's any difference and here's how the fft_df dataframe looks:

```
fft                         absolute       abs
36676.699219+127348.875000j 132525.153195 132525.156250
15539.641602+142518.187500j 143362.876050 143362.875000
61908.781250+18788.427734j  64697.003119  64697.003906
15287.801758+26563.015625j  30648.175830  30648.175781
```

abs is the .abs() values and absolute is the lambda method values

there appears to be a slight difference in the value, where the value before the decimal is the the same but after the decimal it seems to change by a lot. why is this?

also the df that ive used in the line: `df['Open']` can be obtained using the following code, the label names are the same so that won't be a problem, also you'll have to install a module for this.

```
!pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download('GS', period='max', progress=False)
```

the df['Open'] column is of the type float if that helps.

ps: apologies for any formatting mistakes

Comment: Which one is correct?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy thats the thing, i'm not sure. the lambda method was implemented by someone who's more experienced so i'm using it for the time being but I was still curious as to why this happens since abs is a pretty simple operation

Comment: Please don't post blurry screenshots of your data. My head hurts just looking at it :( Please post text as text.

Comment: I'd try it with ints, but since you inconveniently posted an image instead of text (don't do that), I'd have to type the numbers, which is annoying and error prone.

Comment: My gut feeling: someone who knows what they're doing wouldn't write `lambda x: np.abs(x)` :-)

Comment: @Stef oh god, im so sorry, ive fixed it now.

Comment: @KellyBundy oh, why do you say that? is 
```lambda x: np.abs(x)```  wrong?

Comment: It produces a function that does nothing but make another function do the work. So why not just use that other function?

Comment: Checking the first value: `math.isqrt(36676699219**2+127348875000**2)` computes `132525153195`.

Comment: @KellyBundy ah, okay, I was a little put off by the lambda, also im sorry but I dont get what the math.isqrt code implies in this context..

Comment: Well look at the result. It means the np.abs way is the correct one. The other is probably using 32 bit floats, judging by the number of correct digits.

Comment: @KellyBundy ohhhh I see! thanks a lot! ill use that for my final code. weird how they give different values though

Comment: Would probably be better to make the other one use 64 bit floats as well (if I'm right about that being the issue) and use that.